# Computer boots on it's own

Tags: boot

I have a Dell P4 that had Windows 7 and booted automatically every day a 8am.
I downloaded and installed Ubuntu and it still "Magically" boots up.
Could it be programed in the BIOS? I cannot find a way to disable this.

Comment: This is likely a BIOS setting. Many allow scheduled periodic boots nowadays. As such, your question is not about Ubuntu and therefore [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1):

There's usually a wake on s4 option in bios. Turn it off. On all my computers, it's in the boot preferences. Just check which one makes the date and time that says 8:00 grey out our disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a "Wake-On-Lan" option within the "Power" section of your BIOS and disable it. I can't tell the exact section name and option name because they vary across BIOSes vendor, but you should be able to figure out the exact names by looking at the available options